# Restrict sitecore static file under multiple site configuration

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I have multi site configuration in Sitecore CMS.
I know we can add/upload static files to "wwwroot" and they become accessible by URL, but the problem is the file is accessible under all sites:
http://www.example.com/uploadedFile.html
http://www.example.dk/uploadedFile.html
http://www.example.eu/uploadedFile.html
I want it to be accessible only under one of them. How can we achieve it in sitecore?

Answer (score 1):

I would use URL rewrites in IIS for this rather than implementing anything in Sitecore.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

You could set up rules as follows to deny access to the files when the domain name matches certain conditions :

```
 <rule name="redirectuploadedfilecom"  stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(*)uploadedFile.html" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="www.example.com/noaccess.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
   </rule>   
   <rule name="redirectuploadedfiledk"  stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(*)uploadedFile.html" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.dk" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="www.example.dk/noaccess.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
   </rule>
```